# Change all letters to upper case in python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a function in python that changes all characters of a string to uppercase (trying to create the python upper function from scratch). I am also using a find_chr() function to get the index of the characters of the original string. The code is:

```
def main():
    ASCII_LOWERCASE="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    ASCII_UPPERCASE="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    ASCII_ALL=ASCII_LOWERCASE+ASCII_UPPERCASE

    print(upper('i am going'))

def find_chr(s,char):
    i=0
    for ch in s:
        if ch==char:
            return (i)
            break        
        i+=1
    return -1
def upper(s):

    ASCII_LOWERCASE="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    ASCII_UPPERCASE="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"


    result=""
    for ch in s:
        if ch in ASCII_UPPERCASE:
            result+=ch
        elif ch in ASCII_LOWERCASE:
            index=find_chr(ASCII_LOWERCASE,ch)
            new=ASCII_UPPERCASE[index]
            result+=new
    return result




main()
```

My problem is that the output is

```
IAMGOING
```

instead of "I AM GOING". I would really appreciate if someone could give me some pointers to modify the codes to get the appropriate results. Thanks

Comment: That's a long code for converting to upper-case..

Comment: Anything wrong with `my_string.upper()` ?

Comment: you do know there is a `str.upper` function?

Comment: I assume it's an exercise of some sort, but it would be nice to say that up front

Comment: Sorry, yes I should have said that at the beginning that I am not supposed to use str.upper function. I am trying to create the upper function from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A third possibility is missing from here:

```
if ch in ASCII_UPPERCASE:
    result+=ch
elif ch in ASCII_LOWERCASE:
    index=find_chr(ASCII_LOWERCASE,ch)
    new=ASCII_UPPERCASE[index]
    result+=new
```

You need:

```
else:
    result += ch
```

If it's not uppercase or lowercase, (like your space), it doesn't get added

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. I was just wondering about how to include the empty spaces and you answered my question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add an else:

```
for ch in s:
    if ch in ASCII_UPPERCASE:
        result+=ch
    elif ch in ASCII_LOWERCASE:
        index=find_chr(ASCII_LOWERCASE,ch)
        new=ASCII_UPPERCASE[index]
        result+=new
    else:
        result+=ch
```

Edited to correct my misreading of the problem!

Comment: You forgot to handle numbers and other characters that are not letters or spaces (E.g. @#$%^&*+_)
A simple `else` should have been enough.

Comment: You are right. I never thought about numbers and other character. Thanks for pointing out the loopholes.

Comment: You're right, of course, since he says he's trying to re-create `String.upper()` from scratch -- I didn't read his problem carefully enough.

Answer (score 0):

All in for built-in functions! Not sure if there's a reason you can't use this, but python already has this functionality:

```
>>> 'test'.upper()
'TEST'
```

Comment: for what it's worth, your `>>>` is on the wrong line

Comment: @mhlester My terminal is actually like that, but I totally forgot that was something I switched myself. I'll switch it for clarity's sake.

Comment: what an...interesting choice :)

Comment: Man, ninja down-vote on a 3 year old question that's clearly correct. Feelsbadman.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there is a builtin function to do this in a much simpler and more reliable manner:

```
print('i am going'.upper())
```

However the reason you code is removing spaces is here:

```
if ch in ASCII_UPPERCASE:
    result+=ch
elif ch in ASCII_LOWERCASE:
    index=find_chr(ASCII_LOWERCASE,ch)
    new=ASCII_UPPERCASE[index]
    result+=new
```

If `ch` is a space, it is not in either of `ASCII_UPPERCASE` nor `ASCII_LOWERCASE`, and thus is never appended onto your `result`

You could either have an `else:` statement on the end which appends, or simplify the statement like this:

```
if ch in ASCII_LOWERCASE:
    index=find_chr(ASCII_LOWERCASE,ch)
    new=ASCII_UPPERCASE[index]
    result+=new
else:
    # Either already uppercase, or not a known lower-case character
    result += ch
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying your code for a better understanding. Appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an implementation of upper() using the ord() & chr() functions

```
# ASCII codes for a-z: 97 to 122
# ASCII codes for A-Z: 65-90

def upper(s):
    new_s = ""
    for c in s:
        if 97 <= ord(c) <= 122:
            new_s += chr(ord(c) - 32)
        else:
            new_s += c

    return new_s

print upper("What's going on?")
```